# How can I access the response body on a 422 with AFHTTPSessionManager?

Tags: ios, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I've subclassed AFHTTPSessionManager as [encouraged](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.5.4/Classes/AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.html) by the docs. When I do a POST, like so:

```
[[ABHTTPSessionManager sharedManager] POST:@"/api/foo" parameters:@{@"foo": @"bar"} success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
    // handle success
} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
    // handle failure
}];
```

In the failure block I'd like to access the body of the response. Is the only way to do this to [write a custom response serializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29571451/afhttpsessionmanager-get-unserialized-raw-response-body-nsdata)?

Answer (score 0):

After more digging it looks like the definitive [answer](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/pull/1390#issuecomment-26110839) from the creator of AFNetworking is that yes, creating a custom response serializer is the correct approach. (Though that's almost two years dated).

**EDIT**

Nope! No need to subclass. I used the approach outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19096556/afnetworking-2-0-afhttpsessionmanager-how-to-get-status-code-and-response-json?rq=1). This question should probably be closed as a duplicate.